# MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified in jenkins

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration

I am facing below error with Jenkins and MSBuild.

[image]

I have already gone through various pages on stackoverflow and other sites where the recommendation is to put the path in double quotes but that didn't helped.

Following is the configuration image.

[image]
[image]

Looking for help

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to publish a solution having multiple Projects (example 1 ASP.NET MVC site and another say ASP.NET WEB API)? If that is what you are trying for then you will have to create a separate file which specifies the project to include for publishing. Try having a look at this: http://sedodream.com/2013/09/21/HowToExtendTheWebPublishProcessWithoutModifyingProjectContents.aspx

Comment: No there is just a WebApp no other project.